# Não consigo autenticar na api laravel utilizando o sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, axios

Estou usando o laravel sanctum para gerar tokens de acesso para minha api. Segui o passo a passo da documentação do laravel. Gerei um token. Mas quando vou acessar uma rota que contem um middleware `auth:sanctum` com na documentação dá um erro 401 falando que não está autorizado. Mesmo eu passando o token como Header Authorization Bearer. Eu segui o passo a passo certinho mas não consigo achar o problema.

Código para geração de token

```php
if($this->validator($data)){
            $user = $this->create($data);
            $token = $user->createToken('acesso',['tipo:'.$user->tipo]);
            return $token->plainTextToken;
        }`  Rota no Arquivo api.php `Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/users',"UserController@users");` Código da requisição com axios `var token = "aeeeabab01978e8edfcba40f523f54b424c2d956e1dfbf856049ad9311241087";
axios
  .get("/api/users", 
    { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer: ${token}`} })
  .then(response => {
            // If request is good...
            console.log(response.data)
          });
```

Answer (score 1):

Descobri meu erro. Eu estava pegando o token criptografado no banco de dados e estava enviando no Header Authorization Bearer. Quando gerar o toquem deve mandar para o usário de imediato. Antes de criptografar para mandar para o banco. `return $token->plainTextToken;`

Comment: Qual rota vc está usando? seria .../api/broadicasting/auth ? Estou fazendo com Laravel Echo Server e não consigo acessar um PrivateChannel ou PresenceChannel, só esta funcionando com Channel(). Poderia compartilhar sua experiência?

Comment: Depois que descobri meu erro, percebi que não precisava de construir uma api. Então passei a definir as rotas de dados no arquivo web.php  e utilizo a autenticação padrão do Laravel. Eu também estou utilizando o Laravel Echo. Consegui acessar todos os tipos de canais, mas com a autenticação padrão do Laravel. Qual o tipo de autenticação para acessar sua aplicação ("Sem ser o da API"), você esta utilizando?

Comment: Poderia compartilhar um exemplo dessa implementação?